# Testing whether a value is equal to a string value when it can also be NULL

Tags: r

I have a value which can be one of 3 strings, or `NULL`. When the value is `NULL` the following code does not work

```
value <- NULL

if( value == "test" ){
    print("1")
} else {
    print("2")
}
```

It seems I have to write the code as below to make it work:

```
if ( !is.null(value) && value== "test" ) {
    print("1")
} else {
    print("2")
}
```

Writing it like that however seems unnecessarily complicated and messy.

Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could surround the condition with `isTRUE()`

```r
value <- NULL

if ( isTRUE(value == "test") ) {
    print("1")
} else {
    print("2")
}

# [1] "2"
```

or replace `==` with `identical()`:

```r
identical(value, "test")

# [1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use function `setequal` in `base` R:

```
value <- NULL
setequal(value, "test")
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using `%in%` operator:

```
if( "test" %in% value){
  print("1")
} else {
  print("2")
}

[1] "2"
```